# Make Fullscreen imageview match positioning of launch image on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview

In order to do an initial check on a boolean on the first launch of my app, I want to have a splash screen that acts as the initial screen, then decide which screen to navigate to... I know Apple doesn't suggest splash screens, but this should only take a few milliseconds...

Anyways, I want this screen to have an ImageView that fills the entire screen, and the asset to be an exact replica of the Launch Image, so that the user doesn't know see a visible difference in the image positioning.

However, I am unable to get the exact positioning correct on a 4-inch device or larger...

I've tried both setting the mode in Storyboard and setting the image and it's contentMode programatically... but it always seems to have a slight positioning change.

I've also tried to set the Launch Screen File property in my General Target settings ( to be the first screen of the storyboard, which is the ViewController I am referring to), but that just shows a black launch image :(

Ultimately, if I was able to access the actual LaunchImage from my .xcassets, that would likely solve the problem... but, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413716/any-fresher-ways-to-access-images-in-asset-catalog-programatically#comment49923845_25413716), that seems impossible.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS app projects come with a LaunchScreen.xib file now, so I would suggest putting the splash screen image there. Also, when I checked the Launch Screen File option in General Target Settings, it gave me an option for the LaunchScreen.xib file, so whatever file you put there probably has to be a xib or storyboard file, not an image. If you want to use only images, the Launch Images Source option above the Launch Screen File option looks like what you want.

If you want to keep implementing the splash screen dynaically, you should not have to change the contentMode. The code should be something like:

```
UIImageView* imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage named:@"splashScreen.png"]];
[imageview setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Comment: My "Launch Images Source" is set to a .xcasset group called LaunchImage.. that's not the problem.

Comment: and yes, I've tried a xib and a Storyboard (with the initial view controller set to my splash screen) in "Launch Screen File" but always end up with a black screen...

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Try using the default launch xib file that is provided and modify that to have your image.