# local html in UIWebView with images from Assets catalog

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to write code that loads a local html string into a UIWebView with images from the Assets.xcassets catalog.

Currently, I load the images from the main bundle, like this:

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<h1>My title</h1><img src='%@'/>", @"myImage1.png"];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

However, this is very limiting in respect to using different retina versions of the images (@2 and @3).
I would like to load the images instead from the asset catalog, but can't figure out how to do it.

Provided the image name in the html string, how do I load the image from the assests into the webView, while supporting @2 and @3 retina versions?

Answer (score -1):

Here Is Given Code Try it..

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
==> like thi some images :

=================================================================

This is how to load/use a local html with relative references.
Use the below given code.

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];

[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

Now all your relative links(like img/.gif, js/.js) in the html should get resolved.

Comment: This doesn't solve how to use images from the Asset catalog.

Comment: check try it :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052344/access-asset-catalog-programmatically

Comment: thank you for answering, but this doesn't answer the question. I'm not trying to load an image from the asset catalog straight into a UIImage. I'm trying to load images from the asset catalog into html in a UIWebView while resolving retina sizes.